Automatically combine two scanned objects by point(s)
I've got a number of scanned shapes that I'm trying to "combine" into a whole, singular shape. These scanned shapes should "fit" into each other. Think something like puzzle pieces (only a LOT simpler in shapes) - the point is that these shapes fit. Note that the shapes represent a long curve so I cannot "align" them all to one line / level.
To that extent I take each scan into Inkscape and manually, as best as I can, create an outline. I then, manually and very carefully, try to rotate and match two sides until they match almost perfectly.
But ideally I'd like to simplify the process; I'd like to attach one object to another by one of the points (usually a corner), then rotate manually until another corner matches.
Is there a way to do this easily and efficiently in Inkscpae?

I don't know if you would consider this easy, but . . .

Go into View > Display Mode > Outline. This helps with accuracy

In the Snapping controls, go into Advanced Mode, and make sure you have the following options enabled



Enable Snapping
Nodes
Cusp Nodes
Other Points
Object Rotation Centres


Click twice on the shape you want to rotate to bring up the rotation handles.

Click and drag the rotation centre until it snaps to a corner node

Click and drag the object so that it snaps to the corner of the other object

*Toggle snapping off temporarily by pressing K, because it can sometimes mess up, and then rotate it into place


This sounds way more complicated than it actually is. But once you have the snapping options properly configured it should be a breeze. Remember to toggle snapping back on before you do it with the next shape. And when you have finished, switch the view display mode back to normal.
Here's an example

*Note if your shapes have nodes which are perfectly aligned (which is unlikely if you made them manually), it is possible to leave snapping on while you rotate, but you will have to zoom in close to get the snapping to work properly, as it can be a little glitchy otherwise. Possibly more trouble than it's worth, which is why I suggest you simply toggle snapping off before rotating.

The last rotation bit is the part that's giving me headaches. Whilst the shapes are not perfect because they're "hand traced", the touching sides will always be straight lines (I guess I should have mentioned that). So the last bit is trying to rotate one object to "touch" the other, but... manually this is difficult to get perfectly right (albeit a close enough approximation should ultimately suffice). With the snapping as suggested at the end the last bit is going a bit haywire.

I'm still going to accept this as an answer, but if you have a comment / suggestion re. the last part I'd appreciate that!

@MBender - for the last step, try switching off the snapping, that is most likely what is causing it to go haywire.
